# Simplify a where clause generated from bash script

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I have the below variables in `bash`

```
source_FROM_batch_date='2020-06-06'
source_to_batch_date='2020-06-07'
min_batch_date_seq_num=2
max_batch_date_seq_num=3
```

My data loads run in a batches `1` to `4` and `4` being the max batch.

I want to  generate a `where` clause dynamically based on the variables I have above

batch_date and batch_seq_num are the column I will filter the data on

`conditions`

```
1) read all the data where batch_date = '$source_FROM_batch_date' and batch_seq_num >= 'min_batch_date_seq_num'
2) read all the data where batch_date = '$source_to_batch_date' and batch_seq_num <= 'max_batch_date_seq_num'
3) read all the data that occurs between $source_FROM_batch_date and $source_to_batch_date
```

I have done like below.

```
#!/bin/bash

run_project_tmp_dir='/home/$USER'

source_FROM_batch_date='2020-06-06'
source_to_batch_date='2020-06-07'
min_batch_date_seq_num=2
max_batch_date_seq_num=3

export min_batch_date=${source_FROM_batch_date}
export max_batch_date=${source_to_batch_date}
export min_batch_date_seq_num=${min_batch_date_seq_num}
export max_batch_date_seq_num=${max_batch_date_seq_num}


####################Generate batch filter#######################
startdate=${min_batch_date}
enddate=${max_batch_date}
d=
n=0
loop_cnt=0
start_seq=${min_batch_date_seq_num}
end_seq=${max_batch_date_seq_num}
max_seq=4
max_seq_num=$((max_seq + 1))

batch_filter_file=${run_project_tmp_dir}/batch_filter_file.txt

if [ -f ${batch_filter_file} ]; then
    rm -f ${batch_filter_file}
fi

until [ "$d" = "$enddate" ]

do
    d=$(date -d "$startdate + $n days" +%Y-%m-%d)

    ## Case when only one batch to process
    if [[ $d = ${enddate} && ${start_seq} = "${end_seq}" && ${loop_cnt} = 0 ]];then
        echo "batch_date='$d' AND batch_seq_num='$start_seq'" >> ${batch_filter_file}
    fi

    ## Case when multiple batches on same batch date
    if [[ $d = ${enddate} && ${start_seq} -ne ${end_seq} && ${loop_cnt} = 0 ]];then
        until [ "$start_seq" = $((end_seq + 1)) ]
    do

    echo "(batch_date='$d' AND batch_seq_num='$start_seq') OR " >> ${batch_filter_file}

    ((start_seq++))

    done
    fi

    if [[ $d != "${enddate}" ]];then
        until [ "$start_seq" = "$max_seq_num" ]
    do

    echo "(batch_date='$d' AND batch_seq_num='$start_seq') OR " >> ${batch_filter_file}

    ((start_seq++))

    done
    fi

    if [[ $d = "${enddate}" && ${loop_cnt} != 0 ]];then
        until [ "$start_seq" = $((end_seq + 1)) ]
    do

    echo "(batch_date='$d' AND batch_seq_num='$start_seq') OR " >> ${batch_filter_file}

    ((start_seq++))

    done
    fi

    ((n++))
    ((loop_cnt++))
    start_seq=1

done

if [ -f ${batch_filter_file} ]; then
    sed -i '$s/OR $//' ${batch_filter_file}
    sed -i '1i (' ${batch_filter_file}
    echo ")" >> ${batch_filter_file}
fi
```

`output`

```
(
(batch_date='2020-06-06' AND batch_seq_num='2') OR 
(batch_date='2020-06-06' AND batch_seq_num='3') OR 
(batch_date='2020-06-06' AND batch_seq_num='4') OR 
(batch_date='2020-06-07' AND batch_seq_num='1') OR 
(batch_date='2020-06-07' AND batch_seq_num='2') OR 
(batch_date='2020-06-07' AND batch_seq_num='3') 
)
```

`required output`

```
(
(batch_date='2020-06-06' AND batch_seq_num in ('2', '3', '4') OR 
(batch_date='2020-06-07' AND batch_seq_num in ('1', '2', '3') 
)
```

How can I achieve what I want

Comment: Didn't you ask pretty much this question a short while ago and there was a comment linking to [mcve], emphasizing the "minimal"? The question looks very familiar...

Comment: @BenjaminW.: [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62310180/3776858).

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes I asked the same question earlier. I have updated the question with the conditions I wanted while generating the output. I have included my code what i have tried. I have the output I am receiving and what my expected output is.

Comment: @Cyrus I have included the conditions needed and gave the expected result and the result what I am receiving. My code if run as is will generate my output. Please let me know if this still doesn't be an ideal question.

Comment: Without looking at it any more closely, is this really the *most minimal* amount of code that reproduces the problem you're seeing? There's nothing whatsoever that can be removed?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes My code will reproduce my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multi-batch:

```
wclause="(batch_date=... and batch_seq_num in"
```

Then inside the loop for each seq:

```
wclause="${wclause}(${start_seq}"    # for first seq
wclause="${wclause},${start_seq}"    # rest of seq's
```

After you exit the loop:

```
wclause="${wclause}))"
echo "${wclause}"
```

Comment: I tried you solution But getting `(
(batch_date=... AND batch_seq_num in, (,(,()))) 
)` This as the result. Can you please specify the correct places to put your code part in my code

Comment: if what you used was `${seq}` ... that would be an issue; I was giving you a general guideline with the assumption you would replace `${seq}` with your actual variable name; I've updated the answer with your variable name; as for your second question ... how'd you generate the string you just posted in your comment?